# Assign an ID to a button by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, button

I want to assign an ID to a button but I don't know how to do it since I cannot add an ID for it by HTML. For example, I set           `data-show-refresh="true"` then **a refresh button** (the green button) will appear but I don't know how to add an ID for it by jQuery.
Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/1411/

Comment: Please don't just link to your code, put the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem, why would you need to add an ID attribute?

Comment: I want to make an onclick event for that button.

Comment: You should probably add a class instead of an ID. Usually, you want to define unique element with an ID straith in the HTML, and then, on an action, add the class (active for example) on the button. It, schementically, makes more sense because ID is meant to be the same element for a long term. In my opinion, then, you can do this $('#myButton').addClass('newClass'); or .removeClass if you want to remvoe the class on the button

Comment: @yann-chabot: okay thanks. I get it, because I don't know that we don't need ID with this case, button[name="refresh"] is enough.

Comment: yes well, you should just add the attribute id="refresh-button" the the button, and then add a class "active" when it has been clicked for example, adding an ID by jQuery is rarely a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can simply write out your code like this:

```
$('button [name="refresh"]').attr('id', 'yourDynamicId');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('[data-field="name"]').eq(0).attr('id', 'foobar');
```